# Range slider that changes an aligned circle's diameter above track and makes aligned images appear below

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, alignment, range

I have a huge task to complete (for a newbie hehe).

I want to make a slider that does a few things:

1. The slider is horizontal and causes a circle above the moving handle to increase and decrease in size. This circle is aligned and moves right above the handle.
2. Secondly the moving handle also causes text and images to appear beneath it.

For example,

The handle would pivot to the 1st point and show a circle that is 1/2" diameter above it, the words "1/2 or one half" below it and an image of a tool that has a 1/2 diameter. The handle would do the same thing on the next point on the track, but at 3/4" diameter and possibly show 2-3 images below instead of just one.

These sizes are hypothetical, but show that my range is not a regular one. 
I know about DragDealer and Ion.Range.Slider, but they appear to change one variable at a time, when I want the slider to affect several variables at once that are aligned above and below the slider.

Rant done. :D

Comment: incredibly over my head right now. Experimenting with Joe's great Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/curiousjazz77/9gLjo8q9/33/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `slide` method of slider, like it shows in http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  value:100,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  step: 50,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
  }
});
```

The example function sets the value of the `<input type="text" id="amount"></input>` element, but you can perform as many actions as you need to within that function.

This idea intrigued me, so I threw together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cy21o36g/1/) to demonstrate

Comment: Thanks! Your example is definitely in the ball park of what I am trying to code. Do you know of a slider that moves more smoothly. I'd like the transitions to flow into each other more fluidly.

Comment: I'd also want the bottom text and top picture to align with the track along the handle at the current point in which the slider rests. Instead of the text below remaining centered

Comment: Just remove the `width:100%` and change the `left` value in the text span's css from inside the slide function.  Also there is a typo, it should be `==2` whole, not `==3`

Comment: I edited your code a bit to include more increments, and I tried to get the two images to drag beneath the first two points, but it isn't working. I took out the width:100% part.

Comment: you need to actually move the element.  You may find it simpler to used the [`.position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method to align the image and text with the `ui.handle` element

Comment: I just i that, but inadvertently made the circle align with the bottom image/text vertically. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery library like Joe said. It's popular and proven by a lot of websites.

You could also create your own slider out of pure javascript
http://jsfiddle.net/o40w0492/1/

that responds to changes in the slider with a listener:

```
bestSliderEver = document.createElement('input');
function onSliderChange() {
    // Do some really crazy stuff here when the slider changes value.
    // The value of the slider now is bestSliderEver.value
}

bestSliderEver.addEventListener(
    'input', onSliderChange, false);
document.body.append(bestSliderEver);
```